# How to catch CheckedException thrown during field initializations?

Tags: java

I am curious about field initializations that throw checked exceptions. For example,

```
public static final FileOutputStream fileOut1 = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.txt"));
```

this gives compile error "Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException". I know I can use static initializer blocks like below but are there more elegant ways?

```
public static final FileOutputStream fileOut2;
static {
    FileOutputStream temp = null;
    try {
        temp = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //log some warnings, maybe
    }finally{
        fileOut2= temp;
    }
}
```

How about non-static instance fields

```
public final FileOutputStream fileOut3 = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.txt"));
```

this one throws a very curious compile error "Default constructor cannot handle exception type FileNotFoundException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor". Again, I can solve it by doing the initialization inside initializer blocks or inside constructors. But I am curious what it means by "*..FileNotFoundException thrown by implicit super constructor...*". Does the exception thrown by initialization statement somehow propagates to super constructor? I definitely can't do the following because super call must be first statement

```
public final FileOutputStream fileOut3 = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.txt"));
public MyClassFoo(){
    try{
        super();//compile error
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

Compile error goes away if I throws FileNotFoundException but is there a way to catch exceptions thrown by initialization statements without resorting to initializer blocks or bring the statements into constructors themselves?

```
public MyClassFoo() throws FileNotFoundException{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding static fields. The first thing I would do is to avoid opening a file stream when initializing a class. This should really be done inside a method. And it should make sure the stream is closed. That said, you could avoid the static block by delegating to a method:

```
private static final FileOutputStream fileOut1 = openFileStream();
```

The method will deal with the exception.

Regarding instance fields, the clean way is to initialize them from a constructor, or to use the same technique as above.

Comment: Great, thanks. A followup question. Exceptions thrown (checked or unchecked) by fields are re-thrown by constructor, so the clients have to catch when calling constructors. Is there a way to intercept them without letting them go to client code?

Comment: Err, yes, by catching them. Initialize the fields using a method or a constructor, and catch the exception in the method or constructor. But why would you want that? Your object will probably not be able to do anything useful if its fields haven't been initialized properly. Exceptions are a good thing: they signal errors. Catching the exception will only hide the error and cause others, harder to diagnose.