# Why can't I declare BufferedReader in class and use its object on a method?

Tags: object, static, instance, bufferedreader, ioexception

```
public class Example {
    static String s;
    static String str;
    static String[] strArray;
    static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:........."));
    ...
}
```

Error given by the IDE:

> Default constructor cannot handle exception type FileNotFoundException
>   thrown by implicit constructor. Method must define explicit
>   constructor.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    method1();
}

public void method1()throws IOException {
    str = br.readLine(); // I want to be able to use the br object here
                         // or any method as per need.
    strArray = str.split("//s");
    for(String s: strArray) {
        Sysout.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to catch CheckedException thrown during field initializations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592283/how-to-catch-checkedexception-thrown-during-field-initializations). Also see ["static initializer" Default constructor cannot handle exception thrown by implicit constructor](https://www.google.com/search?q="static+initializer"+Default+constructor+cannot+handle+exception+thrown+by+implicit+constructor).